# How to keep only the most recent objects for each unique id in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of the following shape:

```
[
  { id: 1, lastUpdated: "2022-04-08T12:41:20.0106707Z", status: "completed" },  
  { id: 1, lastUpdated: "2022-05-08T02:36:41.0502903Z", status: "done" },  
  { id: 2, lastUpdated: "2022-02-08T10:14:55.0202408Z", status: "rejected" },
  { id: 2, lastUpdated: "2022-02-08T08:11:15.0703105Z", status: "done" }, 
]
```

What's the best way to filter this array such that for each unique Id, only objects with that Id that have the most recent date are kept in the array?

For example the above array would be filtered to:

```
[ 
  { id: 1, lastUpdated: "2022-05-08T02:36:41.0502903Z", status: "done" },  
  { id: 2, lastUpdated: "2022-02-08T10:14:55.0202408Z", status: "rejected" },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Comment: Sort the array by date. Then use an object whose keys are the IDs and values are the objects.

Comment: is your array sorted?

Comment: I will suggest to group the array on the basis of id and while grouping check if previous added date is greater than or not if it is smaller then update the date and for comparison take the timestamp of the both date.

Comment: If not sorted, you can do `arr.sort((a,b) => b.lastUpdated.localeCompare(a.lastUpdated))`

Answer (score 1):

Just check the accumulator or date.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, lastUpdated: "2022-04-08T12:41:20.0106707Z", status: "completed" }, { id: 1, lastUpdated: "2022-05-08T02:36:41.0502903Z", status: "done" }, { id: 2, lastUpdated: "2022-02-08T10:14:55.0202408Z", status: "rejected" }, { id: 2, lastUpdated: "2022-02-08T08:11:15.0703105Z", status: "done" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.id] || r[o.id].lastUpdated < o.lastUpdated) r[o.id] = o;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a `.reduce()`. Your accumulator will be an empty array. For each iteration of the reduce, check if the ID already exists in the accumulator. If it doesn't, add the item to the accumulator. If it does, compare if the new item's date is greater than the existing item's date (convert them to `Date()` objects so you can use `>` operators to compare them).
Don't forget to return the accumulator.

If the order of the results doesn't matter, you can use an object where the IDs are the keys. This will make the lookup for existing IDs much faster.